# MS Edge - Is there a way to automatically log out of website accounts when closing a tab in Edge?

Tags: security, microsoft-edge

I would like the account that is signed in (for example Docker) **to sign-out** when I close the tab for Docker.

I have tried closing InPrivate tabs and those accounts are still logged in.

Comment: Most browsers (any that I use) do not log off accounts. The website will do this if necessary for security. Our own local accounts usually stay logged in.

Comment: Most browsers only clear a browser session (i.e. session cookies) when the browser is closed.  An exception (sort of) is when incognito mode is used in Chromium based browsers, I don't believe a site's session is carried across multiple tabs when they are all closed.  I could be wrong.